# Find index of row in matrix

Tags: matlab, vectorization

How can I determine the row index `z` of a matrix `P` such that its row is equal to vector `r` in an efficient manner?

For example the following

```
z=0;
for i=1:size(P,1)
  if all(P(i,:)==r)
    z=i;
  end
end
```

will determine `z` in a rather slow manner (using `for` loop)..

Is there a way to vectorize this?

I have tried:

```
  Z=bsxfun(@eq,P,r);
```

but how can I extract `z` from `Z`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this :

`find(ismember(P,r),1)`

Type :

**`help ismember`**

for details at command window

Comment: Thanks! But shouldn't it be `find(ismember(P,r,'rows'),1)` ?

Comment: @HåkonHægland yes you can use , ref. the documentation, but I rolled it back.